# Adding a default ordering to a has_many association prevents state transitions on model using AASM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, aasm

So this is a very strange issue, and I have no idea what's going on. Based on an issue in our app, we wanted a has_many association to be returned with a default ordering applied to it every time you read the association from the database. I recommended to the developer working on the issue that they add the following to the association (which they did):

```
has_many :shipment_items, -> { order(product_id: :desc) }, dependent: :destroy
```

That seems to be ok, right? I guess not. I noticed that a few of our tests broke. I have a method in our shipment model that sets a property on the model based on the state of the status that it's in at a particular time. When I log the state of the status in tests, with the ordering applied, it stays in the default state as I manually move it to subsequent states using bang methods.

So I did more investigating, and found that the actual feature is now broken as well. If I log the state using the same process I am testing, it stays in the default state and logging it in the culprit method shows it that way, yet when it actually completes the request and redirects to the expected completion page, the object in the database is in the correct state that I would expect it to be in.  There are some intermediate steps that depend on a particular state, and those steps also produce the wrong result with the lambda on the association.

If I remove the default ordering lambda from the association, this issue disappears. I've eliminated the possibility that the ordering of the results of the association has anything to do with it (the ordering of the objects should have no bearing on the outcome) so I get the sense this is a very strange bug in AASM. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: here is a crazy question, are you using mongoid?

Comment: @Oshanz Nope, we're Postgres

Comment: can you share the code of this intermediate steps